# How to close all open tabs Visual Studio (VS) Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to close all the open tabs in Visual Studio code. I could only find search results for the Visual Studio IDE but not code.

Comment: Right-click a tab and choose one of the numerous options from the menu - Close/ ...Others/ ...To the Right/ ...Saved, like almost all modern multi-tab applications (browsers included). Explore the program a little.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For VS Code, When you right-click on any tab, you get a `Close All` tabs option. Just click that. You can also use the shortcut below:

**MacOS:** <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

**Windows:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

To close one tab, just the usual:

**MacOS:** <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

**Windows:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

---

References:
https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: The Mac one in case others haven't found it: 

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf